# JavaScript (ROCK, PAPER, SCISSORS) do while prompt

Tags: javascript, loops

could someone give me hand please, its my 3rd day learning JS and I am trying to add do while loop until rock, paper or scissors is entered to the prompt but it seems like it doesnt work, trying to figure it out for few hours now... With this code prompt always appears doesnt matter what I enter.

```
// a. User makes a choice
var userChoice = prompt("Do you choose ROCK, PAPER or SCISSORS?");
do {
  userChoice = prompt("Do you choose ROCK, PAPER or SCISSORS?");
}
while (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && "scissors");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

// b. Computer makes a choice
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var choice1 = userChoice;
var choice2 = computerChoice;

// c. A compare function will determine who wins
function compare (choice1, choice2){
  if (choice1 === choice2){
    alert("A tie!");
  }
else if (choice1 === "rock"){
  if (choice2 === "paper"){
    alert("Computer chose PAPER, you LOSE!");
  } else
      alert("Computer chose SCISSORS, you WIN!");
  }
else if (choice1 === "paper"){
  if (choice2 === "scissors"){
    alert("Computer chose SCISSORS, you LOSE!");
  } else
      alert("Computer chose ROCK, you WIN!");
  }
else if (choice1 === "scissors"){
  if (choice2 === "rock"){
    alert ("Computer chose ROCK, you lose!");
  } else
      alert("Computer chose PAPER, you WIN!");
  }
}
compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
console.log("You chose:", choice1, "||", "Computer chose:", choice2);
```

Comment: How it doesn't work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are couple of issues in your code:

1. You are missing the variable name `userChoice` in the `and` comparison within `while` condition
2. You do not require to prompt the user choice when the code run (in the first line) and inside the `do` block. You can simply prompt for user choice in `do` block.

```js
var userChoice;
do {
  userChoice = prompt("Do you choose ROCK, PAPER or SCISSORS?");
}
while (userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors");
var computerChoice = Math.random();

// b. Computer makes a choice
if (computerChoice <= 0.33) {
  computerChoice = "rock";
} else if (computerChoice <= 0.67) {
  computerChoice = "paper";
} else {
  computerChoice = "scissors";
}
var choice1 = userChoice;
var choice2 = computerChoice;

// c. A compare function will determine who wins
function compare (choice1, choice2){
  if (choice1 === choice2){
    alert("A tie!");
  }
else if (choice1 === "rock"){
  if (choice2 === "paper"){
    alert("Computer chose PAPER, you LOSE!");
  } else
      alert("Computer chose SCISSORS, you WIN!");
  }
else if (choice1 === "paper"){
  if (choice2 === "scissors"){
    alert("Computer chose SCISSORS, you LOSE!");
  } else
      alert("Computer chose ROCK, you WIN!");
  }
else if (choice1 === "scissors"){
  if (choice2 === "rock"){
    alert ("Computer chose ROCK, you lose!");
  } else
      alert("Computer chose PAPER, you WIN!");
  }
}
compare (userChoice, computerChoice);
console.log("You chose:", choice1, "||", "Computer chose:", choice2);
```

Comment: Guys, thank you very much, I feel so dumb, haha... I cant imagine how complex will it get later on... oh boy. Thanks again ;)

Comment: You can tick mark the answer if it really helped you. @SmolskisDominykas

Comment: Done, well, it was my first ever post on stackoverflow, I appreciate your quick answer, thanks again.

Comment: @SmolskisDominykas no problem. You can remember me or post your question in SO. We are always there to help those who needs help.

Answer (score 0):

prompt always appears because

```
userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && "scissors"
```

always evaluates to true. You probably wanted

```
userChoice != "rock" && userChoice != "paper" && userChoice != "scissors"
```

Comment: Thank you guys :)